# Datacontractserializer doesn't overwrite all data

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer

I've noticed that if I persist an object back into file using a Datacontractserializer, if the length of the new xml is shorter than the xml originally present in the file the remnants of the original xml outwith the length of the new xml will remain in the file and will break the xml.

Does anyone have a good solution to fix this?

Here's the code I am using to persist the object:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Flushes the current instance of the given type to the datastore.
    /// </summary>
    private void Flush()
    {
        try
        {
            string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(this.fileName);
            if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
            }

            FileStream stream = null;
            try
            {
                stream = new FileStream(this.fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(stream, new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false)))
                        {
                            stream = null;

                            // The serializer is initialized upstream.
                            this.serializer.WriteObject(writer, this.objectValue);
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                    catch (IOException)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(200);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    stream.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // TODO: Localize this
            throw;
            //throw new IOException(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Unable to save persistable object to file {0}", this.fileName));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of how you are opening your stream with:

```
stream = new FileStream(this.fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```

Try using:

```
stream = new FileStream(this.fileName, FileMode.Create);
```

See [`FileMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx) documentation.

Comment: Cheers! That seems to have fixed it. I've been plagued by this for the last couple of days. I didn't look closely enough as the FileMode options.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is due to using `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`. If the file already exits, I think the file is being opened and parts of the data are being overwritten from the start byte.  If you change to using `FileMode.Create` it forces any existing files to be overwritten.

Comment: I'm afraid Reddog just beat you to it. I've marked your answer as useful anyway. cheers!